# Can't call method "get_token" on an undefined value

Tags: html, perl, parsing, web-crawler

Whenever I run TokeParser I get this undefined error. I think it's because the last thing it pulls from the HTML is 'undef' which is causing the error but I'm sure if that's correct or what to do if it is from that.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TokeParser;

sub findTokens {
    my $htmlFileName = "83.html";

    my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new($htmlFileName);
    my @tokens;

    while (my $newChunk = $p->get_token) {
            if ($newChunk->[0] eq 'T') {
                my @lineArray = split(' ', $newChunk->[1]);
                foreach my $i (@lineArray) {
                    if ( lc($i) =~ /^[a-z]*\-?'?s?$/) {
                        push(@tokens, lc($i));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return @tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously `$p` that's undef, and `$p` is the result of `HTML::TokeParser->new($htmlFileName)`. That means there was an error opening the file. As suggested in the Synopsis, use the following to determine what that error is:

```
my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new($htmlFileName)
   or die("Can't open $htmlFileName: $!\n");
```

Comment: I was thinking it was an error at the end of parsing the file but that is it. One of those errors I spent hours pondering over and just needed a second set of eyes. Thank you !!

Comment: `get_token` is called on `$p`, and `$p` never changes. It must therefore happen the first time `$p->get_token` is evaluated.